# destructing nested object in react prop got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const {
    user: { name }
  } = props;
```

With the above code, I got

> name of undefined when the `user` object is undefined

I like destructing but should it be used this way? The issue is there's no fallback to crash my react app. I rather do destruct and use `?` as a fallback:

```
const {
    user
  } = props;

return <div>user?.name</div>
```

Comment: What does the `props` look like?

Comment: {user:{name:'myname'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case that the property you are destructuring is not defined,
You can assign **"Default values"** like this:

```js
const props = {diffUser: {name: "Peter"}};
const { user: {name} = {name: "default-value"} } = props;
console.log(name);
```

The simpler example,

```js
var { message: msg = "Something went wrong" } = {};
console.log(msg);
```

> A variable can be assigned a default, `in the case that the value unpacked from the object is undefined`.

Comment: nope, you miss understood me, my question is if user object is empty then accessing name using destructing can get an error.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look at it @alice_morgan

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
const {
    user: { name = '' } = {name: ''}
  } = props;

<div>{name}</div>
```

Comment: the `= '`' is default value which is not needed, I don't mind got a undefined.

Comment: can the `= {name: ''"}` just be `{}`, imagine user have more than one property, I don't want to declare them one by one

Comment: No, you can simplify like `user: { name } = {name: ''}`. Because the default value always makes sure that it has value. Is that correct? @alice_morgan

Comment: `can the = {name: ''"} just be {}, imagine user have more than one property, I don't want to declare them one by one `
@alice_morgan then you should stick to your original method

Comment: I mean the first default value is no need. the second is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a quick default value an check for undefined or null string after:

```
const { user: { name } = {} } = props;
```

This way it will not throw an error if 'user' is undefined, name will just be undefined also.